# Multiple parallel stages, jenkins checks out source on every stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm not sure this is default behavior of Jenkins.

I have three parallel stages each assumes files produced in previous stage is present in the directory.

I run `yarn install` in **stage 1** and `yarn build` in **stage 2** and in **stage 3** I have `yarn package`.

Each stage tries to checks out source and complains, for example, stage 2 complains that `node_modules` is not present, when I inspected I found after stage 1 workspace was reset.

Is there way to retain the directories/files in workspace after the stage is complete?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 1**

```
pipeline {
    agent none

    options {
        skipDefaultCheckout true
    }

    environment {
        BRANCH_NAME = 'mater'
    }

    stages {

        stage ('Checkout source') {
            agent any
            steps {
                checkout([
                    $class: 'GitSCM',
                    branches: [[name: "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"]],
                    doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
                    extensions: [],
                    submoduleCfg: [],
                    userRemoteConfigs: [[
                        credentialsId: '5db9bedc-fa88-4f64-9e6a-3e9a9d5c999f',
                        url: 'git@gitserver.io:acme/acme-repo.git'
                    ]]
                ])
            }
        }

        stage ('Test') {
            parallel {
                stage ('[Test] Mac') {
                    agent {
                        node {
                            label 'iMac'
                            customWorkspace "/Users/acme/workspace/acme-repo/nightly/${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh 'npm install yarn -g'
                        sh 'yarn install --network-timeout 1000000'
                        sh 'yarn build'
                        sh 'yarn test -u'
                    }
                }

                stage ('[Test] Linux') {
                    agent {
                        node {
                            label 'master'
                            customWorkspace "/var/lib/jenkins/acme/acme-repo/nightly/${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh 'sudo npm install yarn -g'
                        sh 'yarn install --network-timeout 1000000'
                        sh 'yarn build'
                        sh 'yarn test -u'                        
                    }
                }

                stage ('[Test] Windows') {
                    agent {
                        node {
                            label 'win'
                            customWorkspace "E:\\jenkins_agent\\acme\\nightly\\${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        bat 'npm install yarn -g'
                        bat 'yarn install --network-timeout 1000000'
                        bat 'yarn build'
                        bat 'yarn test -u'                        
                    }
                }                                    
            }
        }


        stage ('Package') {
            parallel {
                stage ('Mac') {
                    agent {
                        node {
                            label 'iMac'
                            customWorkspace "/Users/acme/workspace/acme-repo/nightly/${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh 'yarn package-mac'
                    }
                }

                stage ('Linux') {
                    agent {
                        node {
                            label 'master'
                            customWorkspace "/var/lib/jenkins/acme/acme-repo/nightly/${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh './node_modules/.bin/yarn package-linux'
                    }
                }

                stage ('Windows') {
                    agent {
                        node {
                            label 'win'
                            customWorkspace "E:\\jenkins_agent\\acme\\nightly\\${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        bat 'yarn package-win'
                    }
                }                                    
            }
        }

        stage ('Publish') {
            parallel {
                stage ('[Publish] Mac') {
                    agent {
                        node {
                            label 'iMac'
                            customWorkspace "/Users/acme/workspace/acme-repo/nightly/${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh 'yarn publish-mac'
                    }
                }

                stage ('[Publish] Linux') {
                    agent {
                        node {
                            label 'master'
                            customWorkspace "/var/lib/jenkins/acme/acme-repo/nightly/${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        sh './node_modules/.bin/yarn publish-linux'
                    }
                }

                stage ('[Publish] Windows') {
                    agent {
                        node {
                            label 'win'
                            customWorkspace "E:\\jenkins_agent\\acme\\nightly\\${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
                        }
                    }
                    steps {
                        bat 'yarn publish-win'
                    }
                }                                    
            }
        }        

        stage ('Tag & Push') {
            agent {
                node {
                    label 'master'
                    customWorkspace "/var/lib/jenkins/acme/acme-repo/nightly/${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh "yarn version --patch"
                sh 'git push git@gitserver.io:acme/acme-repo.git HEAD:$BRANCH_NAME'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just to give more details - there are

1. checkout source
2. test (parallel)
3. package (parallel)
4. publish (parallel)

Each of these stages are defined for different environment. The problem is when running `package` stage, evidently, the workspace is cleaned up so there is nothing to run package

Comment: AFAIK a checkout occurs only when a `checkout`/`git` step is invoked. Can you provide your pipeline code and a console log output?

Comment: can you share pipeline script, by default, Jenkins Pipeline just check SCM only 1 time.

Comment: As I understand it, depending on how you have set up your job, you cannot be certain that a specific stage/step is run in the same workspace. I had similar issues with a declarative pipeline where I tried to parallelize some testing and code analysis, but without the code I think it will be hard to get a good answer...

Comment: I've update the the question. Thank you all for your quick response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I need to use -

```
    options {
        // This is key setting that enables one checkout across different stages
        skipDefaultCheckout true
    }
```

to skip default checkout.